# Make backup image (.tib/.vhd) as my main operating system?

Tags: windows-7, backup, operating-systems, clone, vhd

My old hard drive is dying so I want to move my Windows 7 operating system to another hard drive. They say cloning using Acronis would do the trick, but for some reason it refuses to work. I also tried EASEUS Todo Backup, but it doesn't work either.  Can you recommend some suggestions on how to transfer my operating system?

I heard about converting .tib to .vhd and then booting from it, but does that achieve the same effect as cloning?

Comment: What type of error comes up? If there were bad sectors, it could prevent ANY imaging software from working

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the hard drive is dying is possibly why Acronis won't back it up. There are other imaging programs such as Symantec Ghost that create a full image of your computer which you can then transfer to another hard drive.

Comment: Isn't that the main reason why Acronis existed? to save OS in a dying HD? Actually, it is not really dying except that it's making a slight spinning noise on boot up.

Comment: Sure but it's never going to 100% fix your problem. I work on several computers that for whatever reason won't boot with Acronis but I can then backup with Symantec Ghost just fine; others will work with Acronis no problem.

Comment: I see. Is Symantec Ghost the same as Norton Ghost?

Comment: This is why it's always important to make backups before anything goes wrong. That way when your hard drive is starting to behave funky, making the prospect of saving data off it dubious, you'll already have a healthy copy from before things went bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) (free).
Even [HDD Regen](http://www.dposoft.net/) to try to repair your hard drive. I have had good luck with it repairing some hds that were loud and noisy (clicking). But it also depends on how bad the hd is... The more time you spend trying to fix it the less time the drive has. A count down to the inevitable conclusion of the end.